# Can I control the function to call written in the __init__ function?

Tags: python

I want to know if there is a way to control the function call written in the `__init__` function of a class ? on an existing framework they have written two function calls inside the `__init__` function but I want to call only one, say the first one only. Can I achieve this using Python?

```
def funA():
    print('calling functionA()')

def funB():
    print('calling functionB()')

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        a = funA()
        b = funB()

c = A()
```

Assume I want to call only `funA` and not  `B`. Can I do that?

I tried referring to the other thead which can skip the `__init__` part using helper class, but that does not seem to help me.

Please advise.

Comment: `A` defines what it means to initialize an instance of `A`. If you disagree with that, you want some other class, not `A`.

Comment: You can subclass `A` and overwrite `__init__` in the subclass.

Comment: @KlausD.Then you're getting into the issue of which methods of `A` that your subclass inherits assumed that `funB` was called. It's much simpler to do *additional* work in a subclass than it is to *remove* work.

Comment: The real question is: what problem are you trying to solve by *not* calling `funB`?

Comment: @chepner: `funcA` and `funcB` aren't part of class `A` so they won't be inherited — so that part of your premise doesn't hold.

Comment: I never said they were. But since `A.__init__` *uses* them, it is assumed they have been called in order to initialize an instance of `A`. *Not* calling `funB` when you initialize an instance of your subclass may be a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @chepner OP and any other programmer's resposibility to check twice, what he/she does and why, what does that call and why and why he wants to bypass it. I saw a lot of example to override __init__() with some good reason, that is why this possibility is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a class, which uses `A` as parent class and overrides its `__init__()` method as follows:

```
def funA():
    print('calling functionA()')
def funB():
    print('calling functionB()')
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        a = funA()
        b = funB()
    def othermet(self):
        print('calling method of parent class')

class M(A):
    def __init__(self):
        a = funA()

c = M()
c.othermet()
```

**Out:**

```
calling functionA()
calling method of parent class
```

Comment: This assumes that `funB` doesn't do something critical for `A.othermet` to work.

Comment: @chepner It assumes, that OP knows, what he does and what he is asking, when he wants to bypass `funB`, otherwise his question makes no sense. Otherwise SO makes no sense at all either, so downvoting my perfect answer with this reason is against the rules of SO. So please, think it twice.